# vararg function with SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) parameter not callable from VBA

Tags: vba, com

I'm trying to define a function in a type library that takes a variable number of parameters and can be callable from VBA using ParamArray.
The entry in the type library is below.

```
    [
    helpstring("Get value from a Lookup table by an exact key."),
    entry("UtilDll_LookupExact"),
    vararg
    ]
    HRESULT __stdcall LookupExact(
        [out] LPVARIANT Result, 
        [in] LPVARIANTARG Table, 
        [in] LONG VarIndex, 
        [in] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT) Key,
        [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *Found
        );
```

I can see this VBA's object browser as:

*Function LookupExact(Result, Table, VarIndex As Long, ParamArray Key() As Variant) As Boolean*

So, at least the object browser seems to understand Key as ParmArray () Variant. 
But when I call this function I get a compile error saying, "Compile Error: Function or Interface Marked as Restricted, or the Function Uses an Automation Type Not Supported in Visual Basic"

The closest question I found is below, but this case seems specific to managed code while I'm dealing with native code.
[ParamArray Not Working With COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354807/paramarray-not-working-with-com)

How can I make a function in native code that has the ParamArray parameter and can be accessed via VBA?

Comment: Afaik VBA requires the array to be passed by reference, not by value as this function requires.

Comment: Thanks, I needed one more level of indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:
http://computer-programming-forum.com/71-visual-basic-vb/a064ce72acaeb9d8.htm

Apparently, the Key parameter in IDL should have been:

```
[in] SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)* Key,
```

And C++ function's arguments type should be

```
SAFEARRAY** Key
```

Comment: Wonderful question and answer. This has just helped me. Stack Overflow at its best.